# Does this function Contradict this colloary?

Tags: complex-analysis

Colloary: If $G$ is a domain and $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and not identically zero, then the zeros of $f$ are isolated. If the domain $G$ is closed and bounded, then the zeros are finite in number.

Define $f: G \to \mathbb{C}$ so that $f(z)= \sin\bigg(\dfrac{1}{1+z}\bigg)$ and analytic in $G=B(0,1)$.

Doesn't this function contradict this colloary? Since I can construct infinitely many zeros $z=\frac{1}{k\pi}-1 \qquad \forall \hspace{5pt} k \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: a complex number of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't contradict either statement. All the zeros you identified are isolated since their only limit point is $-1$, outside the region. The conclusion that $f$ has infinitely many zeros only applies when the region is closed and bounded, ie. not $B(0,1)$. If you had made the region, say $\overline{B(0,1)}$, then your function would no longer be continuous up to the boundary. Furthermore had you picked any open region containing the ball, it would include the singularity at $-1$.

Comment: For OP's benefit, notice that $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=-1$, hence there's no way to extend the domain of $f(z)$ to some larger closed set that contains $B(0,1)$, as $z=-1$ will never be part of the domain.

Comment: So it doesn't contradict the 1st statement since the zeros are isolated and the 2nd statement since the set $B(0,1)$ is open and bounded not closed and bounded

Comment: @adam That's right.